How to make a div scrollable but the rest of the page stay put? (CSS)
I have a div with a list of items that sometimes exceeds the page's height. I want the div to be scrollable while the content on the rest of the page stays put.
I tried adding "overflow-x: scroll" to the div, but that didn't do anything. Thanks!

This question is similar to: How to make a DIV scrollable instead of BODY?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You need to define a fixed height for that div, i.e. in px or vh as a unit. Or a max-height beyond which it can't grow.
Plus, for scrolling vertically it has to be "overflow-y: scroll" (or auto), not "overflow-x: scroll" as you wrote in your question.
